# Touch input not being recognized, totally stumped

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, touches

I have a custom view (1) in the storyboard, and in that view's initialization it creates another view (2) and adds it as a subview. View 2 has implemented touchesBegan, touchesMoved, etc. The view controller has implemented touchesEnded. When I run it and do touches, only the view controller's touchesEnded is called. I don't know why view 2 isn't picking up the touches.

It appears view 2 is loaded properly because the custom background shows up.

I have tried explicitly setting userInteractionEnabled.

Now, get this. If I restart the iOS simulator, and run it, it works fine! But not if I run it a second time. And it never works when I run it on an actual ipad.

I don't expect anyone to magically know what the problem is, but any tips on how to debug this would be much appreciated!

**Edit**: initialization code for view 1...

```
self.myView2 = [[View2 alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
[self addSubview:self.myView2];
```

Comment: Could your view be released when you try to touch it?

Comment: How are you trying to add your new view in the initialization? Could you provide a code sample?

Comment: @Larme I'm using ARC.

Answer (score 0):

For touch to happen, there are 4 conditions :

1. View should be userInterctionenabled.
2. Parent view should be userInteractionenabled
3. View should be in frames of parent view
4. View should not be hidden.

Check if all things are fine or not

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've checked those things and they seem to be satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

I would also check to make sure that the frame of the parent view is large enough to hold the subview. The subview might be displayed but its touch area is being constrained by the frame of the parent view.

Of course, this situation would only happen if you set setClipsToBounds to FALSE in the parent view.

View 2 might be bigger than view (1)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Wasn't the case. You can see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the "Autoresize Subviews" checkmark was the culprit. I designed my storyboard in portrait and was testing it in landscape.  It seems that in landscape mode, the parent view was disappearing due to the rotation, but somehow the child view remained, giving the appearance that all was well.

When I unchecked "Autoresize Subviews" in the parent view, it worked.

Why rotation would make the parent view disappear is beyond me (I tested without a child view and that's what happened). And why the child view would be able to remain without the parent is also beyond me. If anyone can shine some light on this I would be happy to learn something. But right now I'm just happy that I didn't have to shoot myself.